# How to lerp one for every frame, one for specified duration one time

Tags: typescript, game-engine, solid-js

I want to lerp a position `_` to target `x y`. There are two ways,

either the target is constantly changing every frame with small adjustments, so I have to call lerp on each change once like this:

```
  createEffect(() => {
     _.lerp(x, y, 0.9)
  })
```

Or it changes one time to a greater distance, in that case I need to call a requestAnimationFrame loop and run lerp for 1 second like this:

```
  createEffect(() => {
    let cancel = loop_for(ticks.seconds, (dt, dt0, _i) => {
     _.lerp(x, y, _i * 0.8)
    })

    onCleanup(() => {
      cancel()
    })
  })
```

I feel like there is a better way of handling these two cases. Maybe with some sort of abstraction, or a better method maybe tweening, to use a single method for both cases.

What do I do?

Comment: What is "lerp" = ?
Do you mean "leap"

Comment: @tomByrer lerp is linear interpolation (https://www.gamedev.net/tutorials/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/a-brief-introduction-to-lerp-r4954/)